# Map over list of functions

Tags: functional-style

I would like to convert a list of $n$ complex equations to a list of $2n$ real ones. At the moment I am doing it like this:

```
eqs = {a + I b == 0, c + I d == 0}
Flatten[{ComplexExpand[Re[First[#]]] == 0 & /@ eqs,  
         ComplexExpand[Im[First[#]]] == 0 & /@ eqs}]
```

I would like to know how I can write this more compactly, since I'm basically using the same command twice, with the only difference being changing the function `Re -> Im`. Perhaps I can use a pure function to map over a list of these 2 functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Equal[#, 0] & /@ {Re@#, Im@#} & /@ First /@ eqs

Comment: @belisarius you forgot `ComplexExpand`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard One more item for the list I'm sowing thru my life

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
eqs = {a + I b == 0, c + I d == 0};

Join @@ Thread /@ ComplexExpand @ Map[{Re@#, Im@#} &, eqs, {2}]
```

> ```
> {a == 0, b == 0, c == 0, d == 0}
> ```

Or shorter:

```
Join @@ ComplexExpand[Map[#, eqs, {2}] & /@ {Re, Im}]
```

> ```
> {a == 0, c == 0, b == 0, d == 0}
> ```

The order is slightly different, if it matters.

Answer (score 6):

This seems like a good place for `Through`, since it can take multiple functions (like `Im` and `Re`) and apply them to the same arguments, so for example,

```
Through[{Re, Im}[a + b I]]

{-Im[b] + Re[a], Im[a] + Re[b]}
```

For the specific problem at hand, this can be done

```
eqs = {a + I b == 0, c + I d == 0};
Join@@Thread/@(ComplexExpand@Through[{Re, Im}[First[#]]] == {0, 0} & /@ eqs)

{a == 0, b == 0, c == 0, d == 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Outer`:

```
eqs = {a + I b == 0, c + I d == 0};
Flatten@Outer[
  ComplexExpand[#1[#2]] == 0 &,
  {Re, Im}, {First /@ eqs}]
```

Might have to specify the level in the general case.