# Apply every function from a list to an expression

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to apply a list of functions to an expression, like

```
ApplyList[{Re, Im}, Exp[I x]] = {Cos[x], Sin[x]}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you seen `Through[]`?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17460/5478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
thru1 = Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Simplify @ Through @ {Re, Im} @ ComplexExpand@#]&;

thru1 @ Exp[ I x]
(* {Cos[x], Sin[x]} *)
```

Or

```
thru2 = Composition[Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Simplify@#] &, 
                   Through@{Re, Im}@# &, ComplexExpand];

thru2 @ Exp[I x]
(* {Cos[x], Sin[x]} *)
```

Or

```
thru3 = Fold[#2[#] &, Exp[I x], 
     {ComplexExpand, Through@{Re, Im}@# &, Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Simplify@#] &}];

thru3 @ Exp[I x]
(* {Cos[x], Sin[x]} *)
```

Comment: The `TargetFunctions` option of `ComplexExpand[]` is useful, too.

Answer (score 3):

Version 10.1 includes [`ReIm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html) which performs the operation you chose as your example.  You'll need to add [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) to get the output you show:

```
ReIm[Exp[I x]] // ComplexExpand
```

> ```
> {Cos[x], Sin[x]}
> ```

More generically you can make use of [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) or [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html).  A complication arises if you are dealing with expressions which you do not want to evaluate prematurely.  For that I propose:

```
SetAttributes[multiFn, HoldRest]

multiFn[fn_, args___] := Replace[fn, f_ :> f[args], {1}]
```

Now you can do things like:

```
multiFn[{Plus, Hold}, 2 + 2, 8/4]
```

> ```
> {6, Hold[2 + 2, 8/4]}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
ApplyList[f_List, exp_] := Map[#1[exp] &, f]
```

However, without specifying if `x` is real, Mathematica will not output `{Cos[x],Sin[x]}`:

```
ApplyList[{Re, Im}, Exp[I x]]
Out= {Re[E^(I x)], Im[E^(I x)]}

ApplyList[{Re, Im}, Exp[I x]] // ExpToTrig // Simplify[#, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]] &
Out= {Cos[x], Sin[x]}
```

Comment: …or, you can use `ComplexExpand[]`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks simpler than what has been proposed so far:

```
ApplyList = Through[#1[#2]] &;

ApplyList[{Re, Im}, Exp[I x]] // ComplexExpand
(*    {Cos[x], Sin[x]}    *)
```

Related: [Best way to apply a list of functions to a list of values?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/200053/26598)