# Expression to apply a list of functions to an entity?

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

Is there a way to apply an array of functions or others to a single entity?

An example would be:

```
In[1]:= {1, 3, 8, 8.5, 9} //{Min, Max}
Out[1]:= {1, 9}
```

or

```
In[2]:= 12.5 //{f, g, h}
Out[2]:= {f[12.5], g[12.5], h[12.5]}
```

This isn't function mapping, because it's applying to a single element, not over elements of a list (but rather treating a list as its own element)

Comment: I found and duplicate Question so marked this accordingly.  Also related: [(83720)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83720/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This operation is performed by [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html):

```
12.5 // {f, g, h} // Through
```

> ```
> {f[12.5], g[12.5], h[12.5]}
> ```

Other methods:

```
#[12.5] & /@ {f, g, h}

Table[fn[12.5], {fn, {f, g, h}}]

Cases[{f, g, h}, fn_ :> fn[12.5]]
```

Each of these occasionally has a good application so it can be useful to know them.

Comment: Very clean. Thank you!